# Symfony 3 form read only field? (with FOSUserbundle)

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Using Symfony 3 with FOSUserBundle, how do I make a custom field of my user registration read only)

In *RegistrationFormType.php*, `buildForm` method I tried:

```
->add('name', 'text', array('read_only' => true))
```

which gets `InvalidArgumentException`

```
->add('name', 'text', array('read_only' => true))
```

which gets `UndefinedOptionsException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this :

```
->add('name', TextareaType::class, array(
     'attr' => array(
        'readonly' => true,
       ),
   ));
```

Comment: This gives me: InvalidArgumentException FormRegistry->getType('AppBundle\\Form\\TextareaType')
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory.php (line 74). Possibly I'm missing a "use" ? What is the namespace of TextareaType ?

Comment: use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;

Comment: Hm this is working and this answers the guestion. I get a readonly field.But I would like it to be displayed as a label rather than a textbox, So first, I replaced TextaeraType with TextType.Yet I would still like to know how to give it a value (received from a service) but I'll two one or two distinct questions for that.

Comment: you can do that with jquery

Comment: Actuall, I changed the "Readonly text input" appearance with CSS (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757448/with-symfony-3-how-to-display-a-read-only-field-as-a-label-in-fosubundles-r ) and I loaded initial value in model at controller level.