# With Symfony 3, how to display a read-only field as a label ? (in FOSUBundle's registration form)

Tags: php, css, symfony, stylesheet, fosuserbundle

Using Symfony 3 and overridden FOSUserBundle's registration form, I have a readonly field:

```
->add('name', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('readonly' => true)))
```

For now, it appears as a textbox, but I would like it to appear as a text/label instead. I see nothing such as "LabelType". Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like you need customize the appearance of the textbox when it has the `readonly` attribute. So the simple solution could be a single CSS style:

```
// style.css
input[readonly] {
    border: none;
    // more custom styles
}
```

I mean, there is no need to do something special in Symfony and could be useful for all input readonly form fields.

Comment: I was thinking about CSS while writing the post and then completely forgot about it. This looks promising, but to test it fully, I need to resolve my other problem which is get initial value in the field (should be working soon).

Comment: Yes, this looks like what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"read_only" was deprecated in Symfony 2.8, now readonly is an attribute. Try this:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'validation_groups' => ['whatever'],
        'attr' => ['readonly' => true],  
    ]);
}
```

In other case add this to your twig when using the form field as attr :

```
   {{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {readonly:readonly}) }}
```

The right way to do this is by doing it like this and making use of the attr property:

```
->add('name', TextType::class, array(
'attr' => array(
    'readonly' => true,
),
));
```

Comment: You literally posted the same answer that the OP posted.  Also isn't it `'readonly' => 'readonly'` now, using as an `attr` field?

Comment: Yes, I thought the same as @JasonRoman. Yet I'm not sure, how to use it in my twig file? It's mostly auto generated ...Maybe I need to override something that I haven't overriden yet?

Comment: (Yet, adding these values to configureOptions make all the field read-only, which was not what I'm looking for.)

Comment: you should have added style tags to this post